# Can't see the script editor I added to the home page

Tags: 2013, javascript, script-webpart

I have a SP 2013 site. I am using scripteditor almost on all of the pages to add javascript, but looks like the home page is a bit special. I added a scripteditor to edit the home page, I also added some code and saved. But now if I try to go edit mode I can't see the scripteditor anywhere, but I can see the effect of the added code so it is active. Do u have any idea how to find and open it again? I have full permission for everything.

Answer (score 1):

Okey looks like the problem was that I saved only the "Script Editor" at the "Edit web part". But I didn't save the page itself. When I did it started to see the added web parts. Still quite strange why I had to do that when at all other pages it is enough to save the added web parts and refresh the page.